# one image over the other on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am developing a system, where each user can send personal messages to other users of the system. He can send the same message to any number of users at a time. When he selects more than one user as the target, their profile pictures are displayed below.

What I need is, whenever the user hovers his mouse over one of these pictures, I want a small cross mark to appear at the right hand top corner of the picture and when the user clicks that cross mark the user should be deleted from the target list (or any other action - doesn't matter).

How do I achieve this? In essence I need another picture to be displayed above the profile picture (right hand top corner) and have an onclick event for that. How can this be achieved? I do not want to use absolute positioning.

Comment: I recommend you think of a way to implement your script, try it out, pull some hairs out and _then_ come post the non-working code here with a clear, short to the point question.

Comment: well i am unable to understand how to approach this one image over the other idea...... how do i get that without absolute positioning and z-index?

Comment: `"I do not want to use absolute positioning"` - why? It's the perfect tool for the job.

Comment: @thirtydot I dont want to use absolute positioning because i have many such pictures and i may have them at many different places on the site using absolute positioning would mean using javascript or jquery to calculate the current position of the hovered element and using that position to assign the position of the new image and so on. I think this is all quite cumbersome. Isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @thirtydot I dont want to use absolute
>   positioning because i have many such
>   pictures and i may have them at many
>   different places on the site using
>   absolute positioning would mean using
>   javascript or jquery to calculate the
>   current position of the hovered
>   element and using that position to
>   assign the position of the new image
>   and so on. I think this is all quite
>   cumbersome. Isn't there a simpler way?

Your explanation of why you don't want to use absolute positioning now makes perfect sense.

I'm going to show you why it's actually "the perfect tool for the job".

You're unaware of the fact that you can use `position: relative` on a parent of the element with `position: absolute` to make the `absolute` element offset from the parent instead of from the page, as explained here:

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

So, a good solution to your problem is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CKJQ3/

And another version with minimal JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/CKJQ3/1/

**CSS:**

```
.imageContainer {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed #444;
    float: left
}
.imageContainer img {
    display: block
}
.imageContainer .closeButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    display: none
}
.imageContainer:hover .closeButton {
    display: block
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/74c04b6c96836f044ed927a5db4dc92b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" />
    <a href="#" class="closeButton"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/16x16/f0f/fff&text=+" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

put each profile picture in a div with position: relative and then show the nested div with position: absolute (which is relative to the containing div, so you don't need to calculate the position at runtime)

Comment: but how do we get those images to overlap each other?

Comment: sorry i couldn't provide a jsfiddle demo, but I'm at a mall :-) Anyways, that's the solution.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this could help as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/JevbE/

Answer (score 1):

You could have the profile image as a background on a div and put the buttons on top of the image. You're going to have to position the buttons no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the avatar to triiger visability of 'x' positioned over the avatar and set to opaicy 0.01

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // This sets the opacity of the x to fade down to 01% when the page loads
    $(".x").fadeTo(1, 0.01);

$(".avatar").hover(function(){
    $(".x").fadeTo("slow", 1.0); // This sets the opacity of x to 100% on hover
}


,function(){
    $(".avatar").fadeTo("slow", 0.01); // This sets the opacity back to 01% on mouseout
});




});
```

Just set the avatar class. avatar and the 'X' element class .x

hope it helps.